# LWC - Replace Lightning-input of type file with a icon

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

```
<div>
 <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:attach" type="file"></lightning-button-icon>

  <lightning-input  onchange={insertFiles} type="file"></lightning-input>

</div>
```

[image]

How do I replace the upload files in the image with attach utility icon,which invokes the same JavaScript function?

Comment: So there is no way I can manipulate the CSS to hide the upload button?

Comment: you will only be able to pass a css class - so e. g. slds-hide which would hide the respective component. But that will not bring you to your goal as you will not be able to trigger the file dialog. That is impossible - you are only able to execute public api methods - in order to achieve what you seek you would need to fire the click method of the internal input - to which you don`t have access due to shadowdom / lockerservice